# Touch Up Inside or equivalent event in UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview

How to implement the Touch Up Inside or equivalent event on UITableView, means to create the refresh/update mechanism like in Facebook's iOS App in news feed, while user dragging the list from the top down and see the label 1)"pull down to update" -> 2) "release to update" ->  3) updating while user release the finger. The problem is with 3d step...

Comment: Have you tried `[UITableView Reloaddata];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a UITableViewController then you can use the inbuilt refresh control. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and look at the refreshControl property.

Edit

[This](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pull-to-refresh-tableview) is a pre-built control that will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Nope, I'm using UITableView...

Comment: @LifeStyle .. and you for sure have a controller for this UITableView, don't you?